Blockchian implementation in mobile app for data storage
How to implement blockchain( ethereum blockchain, smart contract in solidity language) for data storage in mobile app (front end: React Native, back end: Nodejs)
I wrote smart contract in solidity language on ethereum blockchain. The mobile app is developed in react native for front end and node.js for backend and mongodb is used for database. I have to build such an app where blockchain is used for storing sensitive data of my app. Can anyone suggest me the detailed path of how to implement it?

Maybe there is one package available in react native. apart from that you can use web3 and create APIs and use them in applications.


have to build such an app where blockchain is used for storing sensitive data of my app. Can anyone suggest me the detailed path of how to implement it?

All data is public on blockchains, so it is impossible to build such app that would store sensitive data on a blockchain.
